# Keeping access to Vertices after deleting some other

Tags: python, scripting

I'm working on a script that, at some point, gather some vertices index and access by storing them in an array but also delete some other vertices.

I know from what I understood that performing a delete operation format the vertices's index thus making the array I made irrelevant.

So my question is : How do I keep a way to access those vertices clean and up to date after deleting some other vertices ?

Also, my array order is important, so vertex 0 in my first array have to be vertex 0 in my final array.

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by doing similar to what @lemon advised.

Step 1 : Create an array of the coordinate of the vertices you want to track down before the delete operation.

step 2 : Make a loop to find those vertices after the delete operation based on those coordinate.

Something similar to :

```
for i in range(0,len(vertexCo)):
    for j in range(0,len(bm.verts)) :
        if vertexCo[i] == bm.verts[j].co:
            vertexIndex[i] = j
```

where `vertexCo` is the array of coordinate, `bm` my mesh, and `vertexIndex` the final index of the vertices. After you can access vertices 50 with `bm.verts[vertIndex[50]]`

Answer (score 2):

**Mesh data layers**

Instead of storing in an array could use an int data layer on the vertices.

Setting it up, object mode script.

```
import bpy
import bmesh

context = bpy.context
obj = context.object
me = obj.data

bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_mesh(me)
int_layer = bm.verts.layers.int

# custom int property on vert
selectionlayer = (int_layer.get("Selection")
        or int_layer.new("Selection"))

# assign verts indices to layer
for v in bm.verts:
    v[selectionlayer] = v.index

bm.to_mesh(me)
me.update()
```

Ok now each vertex has an integer in the layer that matches the index it once had.

To test..

Here is an edit mode script to test, remove some verts and run script

```
import bpy
import bmesh

context = bpy.context
obj = context.edit_object
me = obj.data

bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)

int_layer = bm.verts.layers.int

selectionlayer = int_layer.get("Selection")

if selectionlayer:

    print([(v.index, v[selectionlayer]) for v in bm.verts])
```

[image]
*After removing vert from default cube and running test script, I get `[(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 5), (5, 6), (6, 7)]` so it would appear I have deleted vertex previously known as "4"*

Comment: How to have the best Blender Python recipes and advices? Use this link: https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/15543/batfinger?tab=answers

Answer (score 1):

Not really a Blender question?

Assuming that index order is preserved inside the mesh (that should be the case but I don't know if this is specified somewhere), you can:

make an ordered array of the indices of the vertices you want to keep

make an ordered array of the indices of the vertices to delete

then go through each array, counting passed indices, so that you can decrease the indices of this count.

```
vertices_to_keep = [1, 8, 4, 0]
vertices_to_delete = [7, 3]

sorted_indices_of_vertices_to_keep = sorted( range( len( vertices_to_keep ) ), key = lambda i: vertices_to_keep[i])

sorted_vertices_to_delete = sorted( vertices_to_delete )

passed_count = 0

k = 0
d = 0

for k in range( len( vertices_to_keep ) ):
    current_index = vertices_to_keep[sorted_indices_of_vertices_to_keep[k]]
    while d < len( vertices_to_delete ) and sorted_vertices_to_delete[d] < current_index:
        d += 1
        passed_count += 1
    vertices_to_keep[sorted_indices_of_vertices_to_keep[k]] -= passed_count

print( vertices_to_keep )
```

Comment: thanks but i'm having trouble following you, from what I understand you hypothesis is that even the index are changed after a delete operation the order of the remaining vertices is preserved ?

Comment: @EdmondBoulet-Gilly, yes this code assumes that. But I don't know in which context you're coding it and which Blender api you are using to delete.

Comment: I'm using the latest python API, currently I just select all the vertices I want to delete in edit mode and perform a `bpy.ops.mesh.delete(type='VERT')` . I am currently running some test but it doesn't look like vertices order is preserved ...

Comment: @EdmondBoulet-Gilly I've searched a bit.... testing via the GUI is painful on complex meshes. On the other hand, I've found nothing on the web that is obvious about that (included Blender source code... complex...). You should edit your question with this particular point. That will pop the question up in the activity list and may catch people attention.

Comment: thanks, will do after some further testing of my own.